# Setup OpenGL for multiple monitors

Tags: c++, c, winapi, opengl, multiple-monitors

I am beginning OpenGL programming on a Windows 7 computer and my application is made up of fullscreen windows where there is a separate window and thread for each monitor. What are the steps I have to take to have a continuous scene? I am still confused about many OpenGL concepts and how I should handle this. Is it basically the same as single monitor render except with view matrix and context extra work, or is it more complicated?

EDIT:
I found a website with information, but it is vague and without example code:
http://www.rchoetzlein.com/theory/2010/multi-monitor-rendering-in-opengl/

Comment: Yes, you'll have to render for each window individually, setting the projection matrix in a way, that if you arrange the windows by their edges as if they were tiles, you get a seamless image. This is known as *tiled rendering*. It's too late here for me, to write a comprehensive answer, but it might give you some results with Google on the search string "OpenGL tiled rendering".

Comment: Thank you, I have been looking for the exact vocabulary to use in searches. I have not found one however directly related to my problem that is on my level (that may just be my ignorance though). I am unsure if many of the posts I see are talking about multiple monitors or tiled sprites. I would like to see what in the way of API calls are required and a simple method of steps. I know this is a difficult question so I will put a bounty on it when I am allowed to.

Comment: Actually tiled rendering is not that difficult. As it happens I'm currently writing an example for another SO that deals with context reuse or sharing between multiple windows. Your question is a natural fit to put code relevant for your question into that example as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first question would be why do you need two different OpenGL windows?

Have you considered the solution that the games industry has been using already? Many 3D applications and games that support multi-monitor setups don't actually manage their own separate windows, but let the GPU manage rendering over multiple screens. I used this in a project this year to have an oculus rift view and a spectator view on a TV screen. I didn't manage two OpenGL scenes, just two different "cameras".

http://www.amd.com/en-us/innovations/software-technologies/eyefinity

http://www.nvidia.com/object/3d-vision-surround-technology.html

**Pros**

- Easier to code for. You just treat your code as being one scene, no weird scene management needed.
- Graceful degradation. If your user only has one screen instead of two your app will still behave just fine sans a few UI details.
- Better performance (Anecdotal). In my own project I found better performance over using two different 3D windows.

**Cons**

- Lack of control. You're at the behest of driver providers. For example nVidia surround requires that GPUs be setup in SLI for whatever reason.
- Limited support. Only relatively new graphics card support this multi monitor technology.
- Works best wheen screens are same resolution. Dealing with different aspect ratios and even resolutions of the same aspect ratio can be difficult.
- Inconvenient. The user will have to setup their computer to be in multi monitor mode when they may have their own preferred mode.

Comment: Compatibility would be the primary reason. My media layer has a Windows version and a Linux version -- Linux is known to have bad drivers. Another would be multi-card rendering which could be out of the scope of this question. To clarify, I would like to have one thread per card (each card handling their windows). The user could then pick multi-card multi-monitor, multi-monitor single card, fullscreen, or windowed. I do not understand your point about graceful degradation. Do you mean it is easier to implement? I already have multiple windows working fine just without OpenGL.

Comment: >The user could then pick multi-card multi-monitor, multi-monitor single card, fullscreen, or windowed.

You're not going to get all of these features easily without relying on the GPU drivers and Eyefinity/Surround/TwinView. The GPU technologies were specifically designed to address these issues.

OpenGL Tile Rendering will as suggested above work, but how much time it is worth investing into is up to you. My particular criteria was I was writing a game, not a window management engine.

Comment: I have the window creation and tasking system already made that can switch between "windowing modes" on the fly but the sections of code that deal with the OpenGL bits are missing.

Comment: If you're not worried about supporting multiple video cards and you want to go down this path, consider looking at http://www.mesa3d.org/brianp/TR.html for a concrete example of some of the technique used in the link in your question edit.

Comment: That is a great example and along the lines of what I was looking for when I was searching. If datenwolf or someone else doesn't create a custom example before the bounty ends I will award you the points.

Comment: I might have a go at it over the weekend.

Comment: I would have really liked to see an example. Thanks for the comprehensive reply though.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have more time. I've been a bit pre occupied lately.